# npx expo start always starts on localhost since latest windows update

Tags: react-native

`npx expo start` always starts on localhost since latest windows update.

I already tried to delete the `.expo` folder dans also try with `-c` to clear the cache. And also with `-lan`.
No luck.

expo v0.3.2

[image]